# Should we put the definite article before 'morning'?

Tags: definite-article

> My father and I go for a walk in **morning** in a park close to our home.

Should there be a 'the' before 'morning' here?

Comment: Or change it to "a morning walk" and avoid the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should say "in **the** morning."  This is mostly a matter of referring to time of day in an idiomatic way; we say "We walk *in the morning*" but "we walk *at night*" (no article).  It's hard to explain exactly why this is the case, but it's the idiomatic way of saying it.  [Here's the Google Ngrams search showing how much more common it is to say "in the morning/at night" vs. "in morning/at the night".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20morning%2Cin%20the%20morning%2Cat%20night%2Cat%20the%20night&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20night%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20night%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: *In the night* is used, but usually for literary effect; *a child wailing in the night* is much more forlorn than *a child wailing at night*.