# When do we use definite article with morning and evening

Tags: definite-article

When do we use definite article with morning and evening? and when shouldn't we use them?

> - It was **morning**, but I want to sleep a little more.
> - I often sit on this chair in **the morning** to read the paper."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we put the definite article before 'morning'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120126/should-we-put-the-definite-article-before-morning)

Comment: the motioned duplicated question is answer part of the question. but it doesn't explain why we don't use "the" with "It was morning"

Comment: Note that it's (dialectally?) possible to express the second situation without an article, as [*I often sit here **mornings** to read the paper*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sit+here+mornings%22) Or (definitely dialectal) [*I often sit here **of a morning***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sit+here+of+a+morning%22)

Comment: I don't think there is any "explanation" for your first case. Idiomatically the article is unlikely in that *exact* context, but it's perfectly natural in, say, [*An elderly English woman pointed out that it was now **the** afternoon*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120126/should-we-put-the-definite-article-before-morning/120127#120127).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would say that "I often sit here mornings..." is AmE.   And Ngram can't find any BrE references.... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=here+mornings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: @JavaLatte: As I implied, it's a bit "dialectal", but I wouldn't say it sounds specifically "American" to me. FWIW I found [*The doctor's always in the pub evenings*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22always+in+the+pub+evenings%22) in *The Orphan Gunner* - [an unconventional romance set in bomber command in Lincolnshire during the Second World War.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22unconventional+romance+set+in+bomber%22) The author is from New Zealand; make of that what you will.

Comment: ...though I *will* say that the alternative *I often sit here **of an evening*** (also "dialectal") sounds much more BrE than AmE to me. But what do I know?

Comment: There is also this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39107/ but I don't think any of the ones that look like duplicates have been answered very well.